# Error message after installing and restarting Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: error-handling

I decided to install Ubuntu with my flash drive today and when I thought I did it right something serious happened. After going through the prompts on Ubuntu to install, it tells me to restart to complete. But now it's sitting on a black screen with a message that says this

"[       12.323091]  scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but"

And thats it. What do I do?!?!

Comment: Try using another USB port

Comment: Did you pull out the _flash drive_ during the restart ?